# onErrorInsertItem for RxJava 2? Advanced rx cache logic

Tags: java, android, caching, rx-java2

I'm working on cache implementation with RxJava 2. What I need is when network request fails, my repository would insert stale data and show error message. While I'm able to insert Item with `.onErrorReturnItem(cachedItem)` the error gets lost. Also I'm able to concat cached data with network request, but it is a bit cumbersome:

```
public Observable<Dashboard> getDashboard(String phoneNum, boolean getNewData) {
    if (getNewData) invalidateDashboardCache();//just set dashboardCacheValid = false
    Observable<Dashboard> observableToCache = Observable.fromCallable(
            () -> {
                Dashboard cached = mCache.getDashboard(phoneNum);
                if (cached != null) {
                    if (!cached.cacheValid()) {
                        dashboardCacheValid = false;
                    }
                    return cached;
                }
                dashboardCacheValid = false;
                return Dashboard.EMPTY;
            })
            .concatMap(cachedDashboard -> Observable.concat(Observable.just(cachedDashboard),
                    Observable.fromCallable(() -> !dashboardCacheValid)
                            .filter(Boolean::booleanValue)
                            .flatMap(cacheNotValid -> mNetworkHelper.getDashboardRaw(phoneNum))
                            .doOnNext(dashboard -> {
                                mCache.putDashboard(pnumber, dashboard);
                                dashboardCacheValid = true;
                            })));
    return cacheObservable(CACHE_PREFIX_GET_DASHBOARD + phoneNum, observableToCache); //this is for multiple calls
}
```

Is there a way to modify `.onErrorReturnItem(cachedDashboard)` to something like this?:[image]

Comment: You can use `onErrorResumeNext` with a function that let's you side-effect an error, like `e -> concat(just(item), error(e))`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @akarnokd I was able to solve it properly and with much cleaner code:

```
public Observable<Dashboard> getDashboardNew(String phoneNum, boolean getNewData) {
    Dashboard fromCache = mCache.getDashboard(phoneNum, getNewData);
    dashboardCacheValid = fromCache.cacheValid();
    if (getNewData) invalidateDashboardCache();
    if (dashboardCacheValid) {
        return Observable.just(fromCache);
    } else {
        final Dashboard cached = fromCache;
        Observable<Dashboard> observableToCache = mNetworkHelper.getDashboardRaw(phoneNum)
                .doOnNext(dashboard -> mCache.putDashboard(phoneNum, dashboard))
                .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
                    return Observable.concat(Observable.just(cached), Observable.error(throwable));
                });
        return cacheObservable(CACHE_PREFIX_GET_DASHBOARD + phoneNum, observableToCache);
    }
}
```